# how to write pytest command in groovy script

Tags: groovy, pytest, jenkins-groovy, groovy-console

hello I have doubts that how can I write pytest command in groovy script
below is my pytest command code

```
if [some condition]
    pytest test_try.py 
else [some condition]
    pytest test_try1.py
```

I want to convert this code to the groovy script I try but I have didn't know how to write this code in groovy can anyone please help me

Comment: Show us the code that you tried and errors you are getting.

Comment: I try but I didn't know the groovy script so much I learn that why I ask here so anyone helps in how can i write

Answer (score 1):

Something like this. Keep the path to the python file in mind.

```
if (some condition) {
    "pytest test_try.py".execute()
}
else if (some condition) {
    "pytest test_try1.py".execute()
}
```